# Data is not displayed in the FXML table

Tags: java, fxml

In my little project will the data not displayed in the fxml table.
I debugged until every error disappeared but now just don't get the data in the UI...

Here my files:

Main.java

```
package main.java;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;



public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    try {

           primaryStage.setTitle("Stempeluhr");
           TitledPane myPane = (TitledPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/view.fxml"));
           Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
           primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
           primaryStage.show();
        } 
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Projekt.java

```
 package main.java;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

/**
 * Description of Projekt.
 * 
 * @author sandro.digirolamo
 */

public class Projekt {


    SimpleIntegerProperty projektID;
    SimpleStringProperty projektName;
    SimpleStringProperty beschreibung;



    public String aufgaben = "";
    public Boolean aktiv = Boolean.FALSE;


public Projekt(int projektID, String projektName, String beschreibung) {
    this.projektID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(projektID);
    this.projektName = new SimpleStringProperty(projektName);
    this.beschreibung = new SimpleStringProperty(beschreibung);

    System.out.println(projektID);
    System.out.println(projektName);
    System.out.println(beschreibung);

} 




/**
 * Description of the method isActiv.
 */
public void isActiv() {

}

/**
 * Description of the method projektLoeschen.
 */
public void projektLoeschen() {

}

/**
 * Description of the method neuesProjekt.
 * 
 * @param beschreibung
 * @param projektName
 * @param active
 */
public void neuesProjekt(String beschreibung, String projektName, Boolean active) {

}

/**
 * Description of the method projektBeabrbeiten.
 */
public void projektBearbeiten() {

}

/**
 * Returns projektName.
 * 
 * @return projektName
 */
public String getProjektName() {
    return this.projektName.get();
}

/**
 * Sets a value to attribute projektName.
 * 
 * @param newProjektName
 */
public void setProjektName(String newProjektName) {
    this.projektName.set(newProjektName);
}

/**
 * Returns beschreibung.
 * 
 * @return beschreibung
 */
public String getBeschreibung() {
    return this.beschreibung.get();
}

/**
 * Sets a value to attribute beschreibung.
 * 
 * @param newBeschreibung
 */
public void setBeschreibung(String newBeschreibung) {
    this.beschreibung.set(newBeschreibung);
}

/**
 * Returns aufgaben.
 * 
 * @return aufgaben
 */
public String getAufgaben() {
    return this.aufgaben;
}

/**
 * Sets a value to attribute aufgaben.
 * 
 * @param newAufgaben
 */
public void setAufgaben(String newAufgaben) {
    this.aufgaben = newAufgaben;
}

/**
 * Returns aktiv.
 * 
 * @return aktiv
 */
public Boolean getAktiv() {
    return this.aktiv;
}

/**
 * Sets a value to attribute aktiv.
 * 
 * @param newAktiv
 */
public void setAktiv(Boolean newAktiv) {
    this.aktiv = newAktiv;
}

public Integer getProjektID() {
    return projektID.get();
}

public void setProjektID(Integer projektID) {
    this.projektID.set(projektID);
}

}
```

MainViewController.java

```
 package main.java;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class MainViewController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    TableView<Projekt> tableID;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Projekt, Integer> projektID;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Projekt, String> projektName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Projekt, String> beschreibung;



        int iNumber = 1;
        ObservableList<Projekt> daten =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Projekt(iNumber++, "Framework", "Installation"),
                new Projekt(iNumber++, "Webserver", "Blabla"),
            new Projekt(iNumber++, "Kundenaquiration", "Test"),
            new Projekt(iNumber++, "Bliblab", "Blub"));

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


        projektID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Projekt, Integer>("projektID"));
        projektName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Projekt, String>("projektName"));
        beschreibung.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Projekt, String>("beschreibung"));
        tableID.setItems(daten);   
    }
}
```

view.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import main.java.* ?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Zeiterfassung" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <TableView id="tableID" fx:id="tableID" layoutX="22.6" layoutY="54.6" prefHeight="199.0" prefWidth="274.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="130.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="311.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="45.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn id="projektID" fx:id="projektID" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="ID">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="projektID" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                            </TableColumn>
                                <TableColumn id="projektName" fx:id="projektName" prefWidth="100.0" text="Projektname">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="projektName" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                    </TableColumn>
                                    <TableColumn id="beschreibung" fx:id="beschreibung" prefWidth="100.0" text="Projektbeschrieb">
                                        <cellValueFactory>
                                            <PropertyValueFactory property="beschreibung" />
                                        </cellValueFactory>
                                        </TableColumn>
                        </columns>
                    </TableView>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />

                    <Button layoutX="173.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
                    <Button layoutX="46.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
                </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
    </TitledPane>
```

Comment: Kleiner Hinweis: das ist eine englischsprachige Seite. (Small hint: this is an English speaking site.)

Comment: Besides that: did you debug your code? Don't just drop loads of code here and ask why it doesn't work. Please put some effort into the question first (e.g. debugging) then tell us what you tried and which specific problem you're facing.

Comment: oops sorry for that,

Comment: I debugged every error out of the code... Now everything works finde except the data is not showed in the table

Comment: First: Please edit your question (translation, formatting etc.). Second: since your data is not being displayed you obviously didn't remove every error :) Please at least debug your Java code and check whether the data to be displayed is returned by the methods that are meant to deliver it to the ui and also check whether those methods are called at all.

Comment: I added the data directly in the MainViewController to the obervablelist, so it's not in dependecie with any methods I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the MainViewController was missing...

```
<TitledPane fx:controller="main.java.MainViewController" animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Zeiterfassung">
```

...and yes I'm a beginner :)